# How to Change one controller value into another Control

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

```
var getAgentBalanceAmount = function (ClientId, UserId) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.ip + '/getAgentBalanceAmount?ClientId=' + ClientId + '&AgentId=' + UserId + ''
    })
    .then(function success(response) {
        $scope.getBalAmount = response.data[0].BalanceAmount;
    }, function error(response) {
        alert('Error');
    });
};
```

In this method  $scope.getBalAmount have some value and bind into index.html page.here index page act as a master page.i want to change this value on other pages(in content page.) is it possible.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best way is to extract the `http.get()` code into `factory\servie` and use it wherever you want, in different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

set in rootscope.

```
  var getAgentBalanceAmount = function (ClientId, UserId) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.ip + '/getAgentBalanceAmount?ClientId=' + ClientId + '&AgentId=' + UserId + ''
        })
        .then(function success(response) {
            $rootscope.getBalAmount = response.data[0].BalanceAmount;
        }, function error(response) {
            alert('Error');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory. If you want to use factory, inject factory(UserService) in controller.

For getting amount value in index.html, inject factory in appropriate controller and use get method.

```
$scope.amount = UserService.getBalAmount();
```

`JS`

```
var getAgentBalanceAmount = function (ClientId, UserId) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $scope.ip + '/getAgentBalanceAmount?ClientId=' + ClientId + '&AgentId=' + UserId;
  })
  .then(function success(response) {
    UserService.setBalAmount(response.data[0].BalanceAmount);
  }, function error(response) {
    alert('Error');
  });
};
```

`Factory`

```
app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var balAmount;
  return {
    getBalAmount: function() {
      return balAmount;
    },
    setBalAmount: function(amount) {
      balAmount = amount;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in rootscope or using session or local storage methods.  :

```
var getAgentBalanceAmount = function (ClientId, UserId) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.ip + '/getAgentBalanceAmount?ClientId=' + ClientId + '&AgentId=' + UserId + ''
        })
        .then(function success(response) {
            $rootscope.getBalAmount = response.data[0].BalanceAmount;
        }, function error(response) {
            alert('Error');
        });
    };

var getAgentBalanceAmount = function (ClientId, UserId) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.ip + '/getAgentBalanceAmount?ClientId=' + ClientId + '&AgentId=' + UserId + ''
        })
        .then(function success(response) {
           $window.sessionStorage.token=response.data[0].BalanceAmount;
        }, function error(response) {
            alert('Error');
        });
    };
```

Get another page using directly in-session storage with this code:
`console.log($window.sessionStorage.token)` access in all pages